# Lmdb multiple indexes

Tags: indexing, lmdb

I am reading some high-level documentation about [lmdb](https://www.symas.com/lmdb), and it seems that multiple indexes *should* be elegantly feasible because it is, at least internally, possible to have a "data item ... [as] the root node of another tree" ([LDAP at Lightning Speed, Howard Chu 2014](http://www.lmdb.tech/media/20141120-BuildStuff-Lightning.pdf) p. 96). This tree of trees is not exposed in the [API](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/index.html), and this nesting of trees goes only one level deep, as far as I can tell.

For the sake of clarity, let's suppose I want to do queries of the type: Give me the names of all members aged 35-40 who joined in the decade 2000-2009.

The duplicate key feature does not really help me, because I cannot efficiently search ranges in the 2nd key (the member joining date, say).

So I can only achieve multiple indexes by cobbling together multiple databases, is that correct? This leads to a possibly related question: What are these sub-databases? They are not mentioned in the [API docs](http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/index.html). Is this, again, a purely internal matter?

Comment: Wdym multiple indices? Lmdb is just a kv store - you have to manage index semantics at the app level. You shouldn't concern yourself with the nodes of the tree.

Comment: @AsadAwadia Multiple indexes means I have more than one index for a value. The documentation says that a data item can be the root of another tree. This feature would allow to create a multi-index. My question is whether this feature is accessible. (By the way: BerkeleyDB is also "just a kv store", but it has multi-index capability via the secondary index feature.)

Comment: Lmdb is not a database and does not provide indexing

Comment: Really? The name says otherwise.  Lightning Memory-Mapped **Database**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you use multiple child databases in LMDB to build indexes.

Lmdb-index https://github.com/anywhichway/lmdb-index/

and

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lmdb-oql
Lmdb-oql

both address indexing in lmdb.